# Make a Global ViewBag

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, session, viewbag

Is there a Way to Create a **Global ViewBag** that can be used in Different Views.

In my application's scenario, 
1)I have used a **DropDown for Company**  that is used into `_Layout.cshtml` page.

2) For that Dropdown I am passing the Value by making `ViewBag.Company`  in each action.

I want the solution::

1) A Global ViewBag.Company having List that we are passing from each action.

2) Then there won't be any need to create ViewBag.Company in each Action.

This question might be something different.
But How can we achieve this?

Comment: Why would you put in in a ViewBag then? Any public static method can be called from within your view. Basically, any class with static fields can function as a ViewBag if you want it to (assuming you know the data types, which I assume you do)

Comment: Because helpers access the viewbag, and static properties are a bad idea

Comment: Rahul - How do you pass a value from a Layout page to an action? Are you using a post (then you won't get a view). Can you please clarify? Do you have working code where you set the View.Company in each action?

Answer (score 0):

In real world you have mistake in your architecture.

```
public class CustomNameAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
        public void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            filterContext.Controller.ViewBag.Company = "Company";
        }
}
```

I think you need use Authorization and use property User

Answer (score 0):

Add a global filter that adds the Company to the view bag.

Basically create an actionfilter:

```
public class CompanyFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.Controller.ViewBag.Company = "MyCompany";
    }
}
```

And register it globally

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new CompanyFilter()); // Add this line
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    }
}
```