# ViewBag inside of Filters of ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Based upon this post [Make a Global ViewBag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23381295/make-a-global-viewbag), I'm trying to implement the following in ASP.NET Core 2.2. I realize the original post was for MVC 3.

```
public class CompanyFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.Controller.ViewBag.Company = "MyCompany";
    }
}
```

I'm unable to find in what namespace filterContext.Controller.ViewBag would be defined. Is this still available in ASP.NET Core?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In ASP.NET Core, it's possible to define a controller class that does not inherit from either `Controller` or `ControllerBase`. Because of this, `filterContext.Controller` in your example is of type `object` instead of `Controller`. However, if the controller is actually an instance of `Controller`, you can just cast the `Controller` property and then use `ViewBag` accordingly. Here's an example:

```
if (filterContext.Controller is Controller controller)
    controller.ViewBag.Company = "MyCompany";
```

The use of `is` here is an example of [pattern matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching#the-is-type-pattern-expression) that was introduced in C# 7.