# Fail to Use Tempdata in Filter

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, tempdata

I'm using .NET 5.0, and I'm trying to pass Tempdata from my filter to _Layout.cshtml.

Here's my fitler:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http; //session
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;

namespace test.Filter
{
    public class CustomAttribute : Attribute, IAuthorizationFilter
    {
        public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext filterContext)
        {
            //skip the unimportant parts

            string Name = context.HttpContext.Session.GetString("EmpName");
            filterContext.Controller.TempData.Add("showName", Name);
        }
    }
}
```

However when I'm using: `filterContext.Controller.TempData.Add("Key","Value");` , I can't access `Controller` in my filterContext, and the error goes: **'AuthorizationFilterContext' does not contain a definition for 'Controller'**.

Do I make any mistake? Or is there any using I missed?

I've found [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53876986/viewbag-inside-of-filters-of-asp-net-core), but the solution just didn't work for me. (Same problem, filterContext.Controller not found)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the solution you provided, The code is in `ActionFilter`, But your code is in `AuthorizationFilter`. Let's check the definition of `ActionExecutingContext` and `AuthorizationFilterContext` in `ActionFilter` and `AuthorizationFilter`:

**ActionExecutingContext:**

[image]

**AuthorizationFilterContext:**

[image]

You will find that `ActionExecutingContext` has a Controller property of type Object, But `AuthorizationFilterContext` doesn't, This is why you get the error:

> AuthorizationFilterContext' does not contain a definition for
> 'Controller'.

You can choose to use `ActionFilter` and follow Kirk Larkin's solution.

Comment: My problem is solved! I thought every filter shares the same properties, turns out they don't :( Thank you so much!!! By the way I'm using other way to cast controller `var controller = (Controller)context.Controller; controller.TempData.Add("showNo", EmpNo);`, this works well too!

Comment: You're welcome, Glad to see your issue resolved.